# FFT based image registration (optionally using OpenCV) in cpp?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, numpy

I'm trying to align two images taken from a handheld camera.

At first, I was trying to use the OpenCV `warpPerspective` method based on SIFT/SURF feature points. The problem is the feature-extract & matching process may be extremely slow when the image quality is high (3000x4000). I tried to scale-down the image before find feature-points, the result is not as good as before.(The `Mat` generated from `findHomography` shouldn't be affected by scaling down the image, right?) And sometimes, due to lack of good feature point matches, the result is quite strange.

After searching on this topic, it seems that solving the problem in Fourier domain will speed up the registration process. And I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294700/fft-based-image-registration-in-python) which leads me to the [code here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/imreg.py.html).

The only problem is the code is written in python with numpy (not even using OpenCV), which makes it quite hard to re-written to C++ code using OpenCV (In OpenCV, I can only find `dft` and there's no `fftshift` nor `fft` stuff, I'm not quite familiar with NumPy, and I'm not brave enough to simply ignore the missing methods). So I'm wondering why there is not such a Fourier-domain image registration implementation using C++?

Can you guys give me some suggestion on how to implement one, or give me a link to the already implemented C++ version? Or help me to turn the python code into C++ code?

Big thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that the FFT method can only recover a similarity transform, that is, only a  (2d) rotation, translation and scale. Your results might not be that great using a handheld camera.

This is not quite a direct answer to your question, but, as a suggestion for a speed improvement, have you tried using a faster feature detector and descriptor? In OpenCV SIFT/SURF are some of the slowest methods they have for feature extraction/matching. You could try testing some of their [other](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html) methods first, they all work quite well and are faster than SIFT/SURF. Especially if you use their [FLANN](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html#flannbasedmatcher)-based matcher.

I've had to do this in the past with similar sized imagery, and using the binary descriptors OpenCV has increases the speed significantly.

Comment: I agree - correlation in Fourier space is best for simple translation, acceptable for rotation, difficult for scale and pretty much useless for projection. +1 for trying to answer the *real* question.

Comment: Thank you david, I decided to give the other extractors a try. I'm wondering when it comes to image registration, which detector/extractor combination is your favourite?

Comment: It depends on the image content, I've used FAST/FREAK to much success on imagery that is taken from close to the same perspective. I've also tried using ORB, it had more false matches, but was very fast and preformed close to SIFT after outlier removal.

Comment: The [paper on ORB](http://www.vision.cs.chubu.ac.jp/CV-R/pdf/Rublee_iccv2011.pdf) states that ORB performs better on outdoor pictures. Also there is no feature matcher that returns perfect results. You have to like in 99% of the cases perform additional filtering to the matched keypoints to filter out the incorrect once. You can use RANSAC for this purpose that performs pretty well and the results are quite nice.

Answer (score 1):

If you need only shift you can use OpenCV's [phasecorrelate](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#phasecorrelate)